# Getting data from two different arrays for the same index

Tags: c++

I created an array like this:

```
string mobs [5] = {"Skeleton", "Dragon", "Imp", "Demon", "Vampire"};
int mobHP[5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

I created a random number generator for getting the mob number that i want, but I failed. Supposing, the generated number is 4, how will I equate or equalize it to string mob number 5, and mob hp number 5?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function that returns a random number between 0 and 4 (Array Indexes) then the code would look something like:

```
// Since we are using raw arrays we need to store the length
int array_length = 5 

// Some function that returns a random number between 
int randomIndex = myRandomNumberFunction(array_length) 

// Now we select from the array using the index we calculated before
std::string selectedMobName = mobs[randomIndex]
int selectMobHP = mobHP[randomIndex]
```

However a better way to achieve this using modern C++ practices would be to create a monster class and use it in a vector like so:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// Normally we would use a class with accessors here but for the sake
// of brevity and simplicity we'll use a struct
struct Monster {
    Monster(const std::string& in_name, const int in_health) :
        name(in_name), health(in_health) 
    {}

    std::string name;
    int health;
};

// A vector is like an array that can grow larger if you add stuff to it
// Note: Normally we wouldn't use a raw pointer here but I've used it for
// for the sake of brevity. Instead we would either use a smart pointer
// or we would implement the Monster class with a copy or move constructor.
std::vector<Monster*> monsters;
monsters.push_back(new Monster("Dragon", 5));
monsters.push_back(new Monster("Eelie", 3));
... // Arbitrary number of monsters
monsters.push_back(new Monster("Slime", 1));

// Select a random monster from the array
int random_index = myRandomNumberFunction(monsters.size());
Monster* selected_monster = monsters[random_index];

// Print the monster stats
std::cout << "You encounter " << selected_monster->name << " with "
    << selected_monster->health << "hp" << std::endl;

// Clean up the vector since we're using pointers
// If we were using smart pointers this would be unnecessary.
for(std::vector<Monster*>::iterator monster = monsters.begin();
    monster != monsters.end();
    ++monster) {
    delete (*monster);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an array of `N` elements, the valid indices are in the range of `0` to `N-1`, where `0` denotes the first element and `N-1` denotes the last element.

As you have a generated number in this range, it maps directly onto the elements of the arrays.

If you have the value `ix=4`, it refers to the fifth monster. You access the name at `mobs[ix]` and the health at `mobHP[ix]`.